# How do I format the POST or PUT request for a new Repo in Bitbucket API with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, bitbucket-api

I've got the documentation for creating a new repo in Bitbucket [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D#put)

Based on what I saw, I decided to write it up in powershell so I could run this as a script. The only issue is that despite sending a body that I convert to json, it ignores my body and creates the repo as if I had sent no body.

my request:

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add('Authorization' , "$apiKey")
$headers.Add('accept', 'application/json')

$newRepoRequestBody=@"
{
 "scm": "git",
 "description": "I scripted this into existence. yay!",
 "project": {
    "key": "MYKEY"
 },
 "is_private": true
}
"@
$newRepoRequestBody = $newRepoRequestBody | ConvertTo-Json

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Headers $headers -Body $newRepoRequestBody -Uri https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/$workspace/$repoName -Verbose -UseBasicParsing
```

When I look at the request response it shows a 200 success, but it does not change the repo to private, nor does it place it under the project key I specified. The json output shows the oldest project key in my workspace.

I tried this in fiddler as well and got the same response. This leads me to believe that it is ignoring the body of my request.

Is my only option to use curl as shown in the docs? Please let me know what I need to correct.

Comment: `$newRepoRequestBody` already _is_ JSON, so you shouldn't pipe it to `ConvertTo-Json` (you'd only do that to convert a hashtable / custom object to JSON).

Comment: I added that because I saw some other people had similar issues with JSON body and I figured maybe it could have been that, even though a JSON validator tells me it's correct. Without the forced conversion the end result is no different.

Comment: Yes, converting a JSON string to JSON again is _technically_ also valid JSON (just a single JSON string  value whose content happens to be JSON too), but it won't do what you want. I have little experience with [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), and the docs aren't terribly helpful, but you can try to declare `$newRepoRequestBody` as a _hashtable_ and pass that as-is to `-Body`.

Comment: creates a valid object but their API ignores it, and same goes if i try to convert to json again. I appreciate the help so far though, will try any other ideas you have lol.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do the hashtable technique and the JSON-technique (without the extra `ConvertTo-Json` result in the _same_ string getting sent behind the scenes? As for other ideas: Other than double-checking the structure and property values of your JSON to make sure it is what the service expects I'm out of ideas, I'm afraid.

Comment: From what I can tell? Yes. I attached a  -verbose flag to this and it does indeed send the json, albeit a 1byte payload, and a 0byte when none present. I've tested maybe 3 or 4 different non-json objects in the body and it doesn't error out with an invalid request. This could just be their API being incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for checking A 1-byte payload?